# ORA-12514 TNS Listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, virtualbox

I am pretty new to Databases so could not figure this out even after researching online . All the solutions are primarily mentioned for Windows OS but nothing for Mac OS. So here is the issue:

I installed the Virtual Box VM and also locally installed SQL Developer. I could connect to a database and was able execute queries and it went fine. But I had to restart my laptop and when I relaunched the Virtual Box and then when I try to connect from SQL Developer I get this error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De0rq.png)

This error is shown irrespective of trying to connect from SQL Developer instance inside the VM or even through the instance separately installed.

All the articles out there reference something to do with listener.ora or tnsnames.ora etc but I cannot find anything of such sort on my Mac

Comment: Set the service name in your connection to orcl - assuming this is our virtualbox VM

Comment: Yeah it is already set to orcl and the error persists.

Comment: Where did you get this vbox appliance?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I deleted all the files from VM Machine and Imported Appliances again and it fixed the issue. My guess is that Mac may have force quit the VM and it may have been in some unknown state (not sure about this theory though).